# OpenAI check billing separated by Api-key

Tags: openai-api

I deployed some simple chatbot apps using OpenAi gpt turbo api. For each app I'm using a different OpenAI api-key, (each api-key is created using the same OpenAI user).
Is it possible to see historical usage by api-key? It would be useful to understand the spending for each app.
From the dashboard I can only see global spendings, not separated by api-key. I still not have access to the billing history, since it's the first month of a paid account, maybe there  is present the details I need?

Comment: [so] is for programming questions and questions on software development. Account management question and billing issues are off topic here. Talk to OpenAI.

Comment: In my opinion it can be a programming question, maybe the openai-app could help in counting the used tokens by api-key